# Elasticsearch/Kibana: Is there a way to automatically install plugins?

Tags: kibana-4, elasticsearch-2.0

So if I want to install any plugins, I have to run the `Kibana plugin` command. It's a bit cumbersome as I have to install each plugin individually. Can I specify just the names of the plugins somewhere and when `Kibana` starts up, it will automatically install these plugins. I remember that in Kibana 4.1.x, I could add the following to the `kibana.yml` file:

```
bundled_plugin_ids:
 - plugins/dashboard/index
 - plugins/discover/index
 - plugins/doc/index
 - plugins/kibana/index
 - plugins/markdown_vis/index
 - plugins/metric_vis/index
 - plugins/settings/index
 - plugins/table_vis/index
 - plugins/vis_types/index
 - plugins/visualize/index
```

Is this for already installed plugins? Or is it a way to specify auto install of plugins? Can we do something similar for Kibana 4.4.x?

How would i do this for Elasticsearch?